# Programmatically switch TimePicker back to the hour setting mode

Tags: android, xamarin, android-timepicker

I have created a class that inherits from `Android.Widget.TimePicker`.

For reasons of design, the header that contains the textual representation is hidden.

When I run the app, and the user selects the hour, the picker switches to selecting minutes. Once it's there, additional taps on the clock will just change the minutes selection.

However, since the header had to be removed, user is unable to click the `HOUR` part of the time so there's no way for the clock to return to selecting hours again.

**Question:** Is there a programmatic way to return the picker to the `hour selection` again?

Comment: If you have access to the header view since you hide it, Will you be able to get the the hour text as childView casting the header as a viewgroup? then you can call performclick method programmatically on that view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. With these methods you can choose and show minute or hourview.

```
 private void setMinuteView() {
        try {
            Method m = TimePicker.class.getDeclaredMethod("getMinuteView");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            View view = (View) m.invoke(simpleTimePicker);
            view.performClick();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void setHourView() {
        try {
            Method m = TimePicker.class.getDeclaredMethod("getHourView");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            View view = (View) m.invoke(simpleTimePicker);
            view.performClick();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the `getDeclaredMethod` throws an exception when called like that. Maybe it's because I'm using Xamarin, but so far I was unable to fix this in that way.

Comment: Checked at my end with a button to toggle the views. Its working. Above answer uses java reflection that can be the issue for you.

Comment: Possibly it's just the reflection. I'll look into this a bit further later.